# Check if specific programs are installed on a remote server using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I am writing a script where I need to check specific applications if installed or not on a remote server. I am fairly new to PowerShell, but here is the script I have written

```
ForEach ($computers in $computer){
    Get-WMIObject -Class win32_product -Filter {Name like "%Microsoft%"} -ComputerName $computers -ErrorAction STOP | Select-Object -Property Name,Version | export-csv "C:\progrms.csv"
}
```

The problem I am facing here is I can get details of only Microsoft application which are installed and if I give multiple names for filter parameter like "Microsoft", "SQL", "app1" so on. This script does not seem to work.

Please let me know what has gone wrong and what needs to be done in order to get the list of specific software's that are installed. Also, note that I will be using this script for both Windows 2008 and 2012 servers.

Comment: Most people google before they ask : https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/11/13/use-powershell-to-quickly-find-installed-software/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `-Filter {Name like "%Microsoft%"}` part of the script to have it return all installed software.

You probably want to be doing `ForEach ($computer in $computers)` rather than the other way around, assuming you're creating a `$computers` variable somewhere above this code with the list of computer names.

You also need to `-Append` to the Export-CSV command as otherwise each computers output will overwrite the output of the previous, however another issue you'll then have is knowing which software comes from which computer. You can address this by using a Calculated Property to add in the computer name to the output, as follows:

```
ForEach ($Computer in $Computers){
    Get-WMIObject -Class win32_product -ComputerName $Computer -ErrorAction Stop |
        Select-Object -Property @{N='Computer';E={$Computer}},Name,Version |
        Export-Csv "C:\progrms.csv" -Append
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain me about the above script that you have written?

Comment: What part don't you understand?

Comment: What are the values that you gave for "Property" Parameter? @Mark Wragg

Comment: `@{N='Computer';E={$Computer}}` is a calculated property that adds a property to the object named 'Computer' with the value of `$Computer`. It then also returns the existing Name and Version properties. See here for more info on Calculated Properties: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot! You help is much appreciated. But I also have another requirement. Should I create a new thread for it or can that be asked here itself?

Comment: You should create a new question.